# Is this character responsible for some of the murders we see in Penny Dreadful?

Tags: penny-dreadful

In episodes 1 and 2 of the first season of *Penny Dreadful*, we see a mother and child murdered, and a gas lantern lighter and a prostitute.

In the first case, we later see Ethan Chandler among the onlookers at the scene, in the second case we see him having scratches on his hands later on.

In the final episode of the season, it is revealed that he is actually

> a werewolf.

As such, was he responsible for these murders?

---

*I'm looking for answers from current canon — either clues in the episodes themselves that I may have overlooked, or information from other sources that I'm currently unaware of, such as interviews. I don't want to invite unfounded speculation, but I'm okay with speculation based on and backed by canon.*

Comment: We now close questions that will be answered in the future.  That's probably why it's getting close votes.

Comment: But _will_ it be answered in the future?

Comment: I guess my phrasing was bad there, it's more of a "if this can't be answered right now, it is closed" sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is - maybe.

Ethan admits in an early episode that he's "done terrible things", and this may include the various murders. Since other characters, such as Frankenstein, commit bad acts, Ethan may be guilty. The theme of moral ambiguity, of characters who have a dark side, is part of the ethos of the series, and by "dark side" I don't mean the sort of wishy-washy, not-really-all-that-bad-and-besides-it-really-bothers-him-so-that-makes-it-all-right dark that infests most shows and movies.

I believe the ambiguity and uncertainty of the question are intentional on the part of the writer, and there is no definitive answer one way or the other.

You can believe what you want.